# How to make my vim recognize filetype and load the corresponding syntax file

Tags: vim, gvimrc

Currently, I load my syntax manually in vim by `:set filetype=python`.
Depending on what kind of file I'm working on, I change it manually. I think there should be a more smarter way. Probably some lines to be placed in my .vimrc file

Solution:
I had all the standard lines such as:

```
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
```

but the problem is actually the filetype not being recognized, I noticed that I needed a ftplugin.vim at my $VIMRUNTIME and this solves my problem.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't use graphical vim, what does ftplugin.vim do? I mean, it looks like it handles the filetypes... but that's just a guess.

Comment: There's no way this file would be missing from even the most basic installation. That's a problem in and of itself so you should ask another question and explain carefully where things are and how they ended up there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding to your .vimrc;

```
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
```

If you're using Vundle or Pathogen, make sure you add these lines after they are finished.
See `:help syntax` and `:help filetype` for more information.

Comment: I had these commands in my .vimrc but it did not helped. I'll update my problem and solution on my post.

Comment: your answer and romaini are the best. I'll just pick this. But the problem I had was the missing ftplugin.vim, but anyway, still a good answer

Answer (score 0):

Most files are recognised if you write `syntax on` in your `.vimrc`.

Comment: I had that but it did not helped. I found out my problem. Will update on my asnwer.

Comment: I would make sure it is near the top. Also, it seems to be possible if I `set foldmethod=syntax` without `syntax on`, maybe some implicit setting is going on there.

Comment: yeah, i think i should delete this.

Answer (score 0):

Place these two lines at the top of your `~/.vimrc`:

```
filetype plugin indent on
syntax on
```

and read `:help :filetype` and `:help syntax`.

Comment: `:help :syntax` just shows a little about the command itself. The help section has a whole chapter on syntax highlighting if you call `:help syntax`.